# Redefine database "transactional" boundary on a spring batch job

Tags: performance, transactions, spring-batch

Is there a way to redefine the database "transactional" boundary on a spring batch job?

Context:

We have a simple payment processing job that reads x number of payment records, processes and marks the records in the database as processed. Currently, the writer does a REST API call (to the payment gateway), processes the API response and marks the records as processed. We're doing a chunk oriented approach so the updates aren't flushed to the database until the whole chunk has completed. Since, basically the whole read/write is within a transaction, we are starting to see excessive database locks and contentions. For example, if the API takes a long time to respond (say 30 seconds), the whole application starts to suffer.

We can obviously reduce the timeout for the API call to be a smaller value.. but that still doesn't solve the issue of the tables potentially getting locked for longer than desirable duration. Ideally, we want to keep the database transaction as short lived as possible. Our thought is that if the "meat" of what the job does can be done outside of the database transaction, we could get around this issue. So, if the API call happens outside of a database transaction.. we can afford it to take a few more seconds to accept the response and not cause/add to the long lock duration.

Is this the right approach? If not, what would be the recommended way to approach this "simple" job in spring-batch fashion? Are there other batch tools better suited for the task? (if spring-batch is not the right choice).

Open to providing more context if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a precise answer to all your questions but I will try to give some guidelines.

> Since, basically the whole read/write is within a transaction, we are starting to see excessive database locks and contentions. For example, if the API takes a long time to respond (say 30 seconds), the whole application starts to suffer.

Since its inception, the term batch processing or processing data in "batches" is based on the idea that a batch of records is treated as a unit: either all records are processed (whatever the term "process" means) or none of the records is processed. This "all or nothing" semantic is exactly what Spring Batch implements in its chunk-oriented processing model. Achieving such a (powerful) property comes with trade-offs. In your case, you need to make a trade-off between consistency and responsiveness.

> We can obviously reduce the timeout for the API call to be a smaller value.. but that still doesn't solve the issue of the tables potentially getting locked for longer than desirable duration.

The chunk-size is the most impactful parameter on the transaction behaviour. What you can do is try to reduce the number of records to be processed within a single transaction and see the result. There is no best value, this is an empirical process. This will also depend on the responsiveness of the API you are calling during the processing of a chunk.

> Our thought is that if the "meat" of what the job does can be done outside of the database transaction, we could get around this issue. So, if the API call happens outside of a database transaction.. we can afford it to take a few more seconds to accept the response and not cause/add to the long lock duration.

A common technique to avoid doing such updates on a live system is to offload the processing against another datastore and then replicate the updates in a single transaction. The idea is to mark records with a given batch id and copy those records to a different datastore (or even a temporary table within the same datastore) that the batch process can use without impacting the live datastore. Once the processing is done (which could be done in parallel to improve performance), records can be marked as processed in the live system within in a single transaction (this is usually very fast and could be based on the batch id to identify which records to update).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Ultimately, I suppose it depends on what a particular job does, but this implies that almost any spring batch job that read and write to a production datastore are better off keeping their own staging tables for spring batch to work on?

For this particular job, we have our read page size set to 100 and a chuck size of 10. Is this type of read page size value different from the chunk size config recommended?

Comment: Not necessarily, tables could be shared as long as transaction boundaries are clear. In regards to page size and chunk size, it is better to set them to the same value, see javadoc here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html: `Setting a fairly large page size and using a commit interval that matches the page size should provide better performance.`